# run a tool with python>=3.6 on galaxy-project instance that runs on python2.7

Tags: python, galaxy

I am developing a wrapper for a bioinformatics tool writen in python3.

The native Galaxy-project runs on python2.7.

How can I the tool that requires python3 in a galaxy-project instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each Galaxy tool uses its own (typically conda-based) environment, which will normally not use the same python as Galaxy itself (note that Galaxy can run under python 3). An example of this is deepTools, which is python 3 only but will happily run under a python 2 Galaxy since conda is being used to create a python 3 environment for it. It's best to distribute your tool via bioconda and then Galaxy will be easily able to install it.

Comment: I hope I did it the right way: 1- `conda create ...`, 2-`conda install ...`, etc...

Comment: Yes, though it's best to allow galaxy to make the env for you and put a copy of the wrapper in the toolshed.